# Which framework for my small single-page web application is the best fit?

Tags: web-apps, javascript, framework, react, angularjs

I'm currently starting a small project which consists of creating a single-page web application which is capable of modeling node-based networks. The functionality of this network is to visualize incoming data-streams of another application in real-time. The amount of user will probably be really small, but the software should be easily expandable in terms of funtionality.

I'm looking for a framework that fits best for this small project, I've already been looking at the most popular ones like Angular 2, React, Vue.js and Backbone. I should add that I'm quite new to web-development, but have some experience in JAVA-programming. Hopefully someone with experience can recommend me something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me Angular 2 fits there. Java devs usually find it quite natural - the TypeScript syntax and framework's OOP principles. Being an opinionated framework also kinda helps to kickstart the development if you don't have JS background.

Comment: Q: "small", A: "Angular"?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like most of the content has to be created in real time and there is not too much other content to show? Maybe you can try the [Document Makeup Library (DML)](https://github/efpage/DML)? This is a dependency free library tp create Single page applications in Javascript. Makes it very easy to create dynamic elements depending on external data.